# how to use joda timing in java

Tags: java, jodatime

currently i am using calendar type..

```
GregorianCalendar gcalendar = new GregorianCalendar();
// Display current time and date information.

System.out.print("Date: ");
System.out.print(gcalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH)+1);
//System.out.print(Calendar.MONTH);
System.out.print(" " + gcalendar.get(Calendar.DATE) + " ");
System.out.println(year = gcalendar.get(Calendar.YEAR));

System.out.print("Time: ");
System.out.print(gcalendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) + ":");
//System.out.print(Calendar.HOUR + ":");
System.out.print(gcalendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE) + ":");
System.out.println(gcalendar.get(Calendar.SECOND));
```

i want to use joda timing ... 
what should i do..

Comment: Please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)...

Comment: If you want to use Joda Time, use Joda Time - and indeed, it's much better than the `Calendar` API. Read the documentation - it's really pretty simple. I'd recommend using `DateFormatter` instead of all this hand-formatting though. (Do you really want times such as 8:7:5 instead of 08:07:05?)

Comment: Take a look at this post http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-calculate-date-time-difference-in-java/

Answer (score 0):

You haven't stated in which case you would use the *Joda-Time* library, but the basics are stated in [the website](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/index.html).

[Here](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/key_chronology.html) you can refer also to how to use the *Joda-Time* `Chronology`, one of the key concepts behind the library (which I highly recommend to read to grasp the basics). Here down a sample using the *Gregorian* calendar:

```java
DateTimeZone zone = DateTimeZone.forID("Europe/London");
Chronology gregorian= GregorianChronology.getInstance(zone);

// current time with gregorian chronology
DateTime dt = new DateTime(gregorian);

int month = dt.getMonthOfYear(); // gets the current gregorian month
int year = dt.getYear();   // gets the current gregorian year
int day = dt.getDayOfMonth() // gets the current gregorian day
// ...
```